# Checking product stock against a date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Excuse my lack of knowledge! I'm working on a system (PHP & MySQL) that will allow customers to rent machinery. It allows users to sign up, enter details about their job (location, job duration/dates), browse machinery/other products, add products to their basket and confirm the hire. The booking will be processed by an employee and the machinery/products will be delivered to the customer on the date specified. The system isn't required to process payments as invoices will be issued upon delivery.

I have a products table in the database that includes the name, description, image, stock_quantity and daily_price.

I also have a hire table that includes customer_id, start_date, end_date etc.

I want to be able to check to make sure products are available on specified dates to avoid double booking.

How would I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the sound of it, I would start by hiring a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return all the products that are not already hired on the specified date:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) in_use
           FROM hire
           WHERE :specified_date BETWEEN h.start_date AND h.END_DATE
           GROUP BY product_id) h ON h.product_id = p.id 
WHERE stock_quantity - IFNULL(in_use, 0) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If there were 10 of the same product in stock and somebody hires one, wouldn't that query stop the product from showing even though there are 9 still available?

Comment: I've rewritten it to use a subquery that counts the number of hired items and subtracts it from the total quantity.